# Reversed values from slope analysis of DEM in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, slope

I have a DEM as a Geotiff and I have conducted slope analysis in QGIS. I've done this many times and everything was ok but this time I received reversed values: 0 for max slope and 89 for min slope. I have no idea what is wrong. Geotiff was generated from .asc files and seems to be ok.

I suppose there is something wrong with the first Geotiff file.
I took "native" .asc file and made slope analysis without a problem.
After that I generated Geotiff from the Slope.asc and is also fine.

Comment: Which tool did you use to calculate slope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not try to inverse the max and min slope vlaues in QGIS, providing that is what software you are using.  I use .asc files all the time, but not seen this issue.